# adding some elements to edittext i.e some character between any word

Tags: android

I need to receive user's input from an edittext, then add some elements inside it?
how can I do it programmatically?
let me explain: 
user enters this phrase : ( Hello World ) 
I want my app change it to : ( H**o**el**p**lo**m** w**w**o**e**rl**l**d**c**) for example
Any suggestion?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

get the text from your edittext

```
String userInput = myEditText.getText().toString();
```

and then modify it as you want

To 'Modify' the String you can do it in many ways

You can use substrings , replace() , ... etc

also you can convert it to char array and modify it , then build your string again

```
String userInput = myEditText.getText().toString();
char[] myArray = userInput.toCharArray();
// your modification(s) here
userInput = new String(myArray);
```

Comment: would you please complete my example?

Comment: @Tasallot Give more info , what is the pattern you want ??

Comment: you said MODIFY IT! I dont know how to add some character between a string!

Comment: @Tasallot Check the answer again (Edited)

Comment: my modification is like this: adding some random char to a word that received by edittext. when i change a word to char how can I add some random characters between it? for example (world) become (woorllde)

Comment: ok , it's easy .. do some search about **string manipulation in java** and try to do it , if you got stuck at a specific point post your code and ask about this point

Comment: thanks a lot. just one more help! I want to SMS this manipulated text to another cellphone.if my app installed on that cellphone, how can I retrieve the original phrase?

Comment: This should be added to another question , it's always an algorithm part to know your 'encryption' technique and then you decrypt it based on your algorithm on the other client's phone